# JSP form submission with parameters both String and Integer

Tags: java, jsp

I am making a form with variable which consists of both String and Integer variables.

ie the parameters that I'm getting from the page1.jsp page are name1,place1,country1,name2,place2,country2,name3,place3,country3.

I want to get these variables and print on the page2.jsp.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    for(i=1;i>=3;i++)
    {
        String name(i) = request.getParameter("name"+i);
        String place(i) = request.getParameter("place"+i);
        String country(i) = request.getParameter("country"+i);
    }
    for(i=1;i>=3;i++)
    {
        out.println(name(i));
        out.println(place(i));
        out.println(country(i));
    }
```

*the ERRORS I'm getting are:*

```
            Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    6:      int i;
    7:      for(i=1;i>=j;i++)
    8:      {
    9:          String name(i) = request.getParameter("name"+i);
    10:         String place(i) = request.getParameter("place"+i);
    11:         String country(i) = request.getParameter("country"+i);
    12:     }

        An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /page2.jsp Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
        An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /page2.jsp
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
```

Comment: why do you have (i) in your variable maybe you should use square brackets `[]` and it is not an array

Comment: @Ker p pag  I have tried in that way, but I got errors like these                `An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /page2.jsp
Syntax error on token "i", delete this token,An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /page2.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you've a wrong condition in your loop.

```
for(i=1;i>=3;i++) // this i>=3 will return false since i is not greater than or equal to 3.
```

change the condition of your loop to less than or equal to 3.

```
   for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        name[i]= request.getParameter("name"+i);
        place[i] = request.getParameter("place"+i);
        country[i] = request.getParameter("country"+i);
    /*
       it will access the ff.
       "name1" to "name3"
       "place1" to "place3"
       "country1" to "country3"
     */

    }
```

then change your declaration of array size to 4, since your accessing above the index 3.

```
String[] name = new String[4]; 
String[] place = new String[4];
String[] country = new String[4];
```

Also your getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` because you've accessed an illegal index. Your index is negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array that why it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, make sure you access a legal index.

If you have something like this, it will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you access the equal size of an array;

```
String[] name = new String[3];
out.println(name[3]); //you can only access 0 - 2 index, thats whay it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,
```

Comment: @ user23123412 'I'll try and let you know. Thanks for your time.'

Answer (score 0):

you are not using an array

try to make it this way

```
String[] name = new String[3];
String[] place = new String[3];
String[] country = new String[3];


  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        name[i]= request.getParameter("name"+i);
        place[i] = request.getParameter("place"+i);
        country[i] = request.getParameter("country"+i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        out.println(name[i]);
        out.println(place[i]);
        out.println(country[i]);
    }
```

Comment: **what if I need 'n' no.of variables instead of '3' ?**

Comment: from your implementation i think the size of data is static to the array.

Comment: @ Ker p pag 'I'm also getting an error'`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` 'when printing the variables'

Comment: the error is this `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /page2.jsp at line 16
13: 
14:    for(i=1;i>3;i++)
15:    {
16:     name[i] = request.getParameter("name"+i);
17:     place[i] = request.getParameter("place"+i);
root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Comment: @ Ker p pag, Thanks for trying, but I'm still getting error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`, But I've tried manually getParameter and even print manually.

Comment: index out of bounds means that the loop is greater the size than the array. just check the size manually first just for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your previous page from which the value is coming..

to store in an array, there is also a another method

```
String[] name= request.getParameterValues("name");

String[] place= request.getParameterValues("place");

String[] country= request.getParameterValues("country");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 out.println(name[i]);

  out.println(place[i]);

  out.println(country[i]);

}
```